# Assets: Log's me out of the cp

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, control-panel

I have just installed Assets. But it keeps logging me out of the CP. This error occurs (console): POST http://centiv.local/admin/ 500 (Internal Server Error) It contains: {"error":"

This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.</p>"}

This happens when I:

- Visit Modules -> Assets.
- Try to upload a file in a Assets field.

I have added this to my config file: $config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y"; This doesn't give an error but a blank page when I try to access assets from the field in a channel, it say's I'm logged out of the CP.

I don't know what's going on here, any help would me much appreciated! :)

Assets: 2.3.2
ExpressionEngine: 2.8.1

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I have found the problem! It was a the setting: "URL to the root directory of your site" under "General configuration" that contained a wrong path :).

Answer (score 1):

A white page in EE pretty much always means a PHP error that is being suppressed.

Here are details from the EE docs on how to troubleshoot blank pages:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

> Follow these instructions until you are able to see the error
> message(s) being output by your server:
>
> Open your site’s main index.php file and under the Error Reporting section change:
>
> $debug = 0;
>
> to:
>
> $debug = 1;
>
> Go to Admin ‣ System Administration ‣ Output and Debugging and ensure that Debug Preference is set to 1: PHP/SQL error messages shown
> only to Super Admins.
>
> Go to Tools ‣ Utilities ‣ PHP Info and search the page for “display_errors”. Ensure it is set to On under the Local column. If it
> is not, your host can help change this setting for you.
>
> Check your server’s error logs or contact your host to assist you in cases where errors are being output to logs and not to the screen.

Comment: Hi Anna, Thank you for this answer! I'm sorry but I havent formulated myself clear enough. The page isn't actually a blank page. It says something along the lines of: You are logged out of the control panel. The errors I'm getting are visible through the console as stated above.